# Differential $1$-form and proof of an open disc and open circular annulus not being diffeomorphic

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, proof-writing, vector-analysis

There is one example in my script about an application of a differential $1$ form in proving some subsets of $\Bbb R^2$ aren't diffeomorphic. As far as I've understood the explanation, we used a $C^2$ diffeomorphism and I don't understand how it's non-existence implies the non-existanece of a $C^1$ diffeomorphism. Here it goes, verbatim from Croatian:

> Using differential $1$- froms, we can show certain subsets of $\Bbb R^2$ aren't diffeomorphic.
>
> $\underline{\boldsymbol{\text{example } 17.33}:}$ For $c\in\Bbb R^2,$  and $0<r<s$ let's denote by $B(c,r)$ and $B(c,r,s)$ the open disc centered at $c$ of radius $r$ and open circular annulus centered at $c$ with the inner radius $r$ and outer radius $s$ respectively. Since $B(c,r)$ is convex (and in particular, it's a 'star-like' set), every closed differential $1$-form of class $C^1$ on $B(c,r)$ is exact. On the other hand, there are closed differential $1$-forms on $B(c,r,s)$ which aren't exact. Namely, for $c=(c_1,c_2),$ let $\omega_c$ denote the angular form centered at $c$: $$\omega_c=\frac{-(y-c_2)dx+(x-c_1)dy}{(x-c_1)^2+(y-c_2)^2}.$$ Then,  $\omega_c$ is a well defined $1$-form on $B(c,r,s)\subset\Bbb R^2\setminus\{c\}$ and $d\omega_c=0,$ (that is, $\omega_c$ is closed). On the other hand, for $p=\frac{r+s}2$ let $\gamma:[0,2\pi]\to B(c,r,s)$ be a parametrization of the circle $\{(x,y)\in\Bbb R^2\mid\|x-c\|=p\}\subset B(c,r,s)$ defined by $\gamma(t)=(c_1+p\cos t,c_2+p\sin t).$ Then,
>
> $\begin{aligned}&\color{white}=\int_\gamma\omega_c\\&=\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{-p\sin t(-p\sin t)+p\cos t(p\cos t)}{(p\cos t)^2+(p\sin t)^2}dt\\&=\int_0^{2\pi}dt=2\pi\end{aligned}$
>
> Suppose there exists a $C^2$ diffeomorphism $\boldsymbol F:B(c,r)\to B(c,r,s).$ Then, it would hold, $$\int_{\boldsymbol F^{-1}\circ\gamma} \boldsymbol F^*(\omega_c)=\int_\gamma\omega_c=2\pi\tag 1$$ Since the pullback and the differential commute, $\boldsymbol F^*(\omega_c)$ a is closed $1$-form on $B(c,r)$ and hence exact. Since $F^{-1}\circ\gamma$ is a closed path in $B(c,r),$ $$\int_{\boldsymbol F^{-1}\circ\gamma}\boldsymbol F^*(\omega_c)=0,$$ which is a contradition with  $(1)$.

In a lemma where we've proven that the pullback and the differential of a $1$-form commute, there was an assumption on $\boldsymbol F$ being a $C^2$ diffeomorphism and in the proof by brute-force computation, we recalled the Schwarz theorem which requires continuous second derivatives. I believe, for the same reason, $\boldsymbol F$ is said to be of class $C^2$ in the above example. However, I'm missing why this example proves the two sets aren't diffeomorphic. I thought we should prove there isn't a $C^1$-diffeomorphism $\boldsymbol F:B(c,r)\to B(c,r,s),$ and, indeed, I found, only the text, of the same task in an old exam where it is explicitly stated one should prove there isn't a $C^1$ diffeomorphism. I see the converse is true by contrapositive, but I can't grasp how we know there isn't a $C^1$-diffeomorphism based on the non-existence of a $C^2$-diffeomorphism.

> Is there a fallacy in this approach, or does the pullback not require a $C^2$-diffeomorphism $\boldsymbol F$ in order to commute with the differential?

$\boldsymbol{\text{ P. S}:}$ I tried to summarize the material, but we have been warned some of the terminology we use is not conventional around the world, so feel free to let me know if I should clarify anything regarding the terminology or my background on the matter.